# Fix parameters of a class

Tags: python, oop, object

I have a class that takes in three different `objective` types. Let's assume the class name is `BaseEstimator` and it accepts three modes- `'obj_1'`, `'obj_2'` and `'obj_3'` for the `objective` parameter. Now I want to create three classes, one for each of the objective types. These classes will by default pass in each of the objective type. so for example `FixedEstimator_Obj1` will have `objective = 'obj_1'`.

I understand I can do this by doing something like this in the `__init__` function of the `FixedEstimator_Obj1` class:

```
class FixedEstimator_Obj1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.base_estimator = BaseEstimator(objective='obj_1')
```

The issue with this approach is that when I want to access an attribute or a use a method of the `BaseEstimator`, I'll have to access it through the `base_estimator` like so

```
fe_obj1 = FixedEstimator_Obj1()
fe_obj1.base_estimator.some_method()
```

What I am looking for is a way that will allow me to write the above as

```
fe_obj1.some_method()
```

How do I this?

Comment: It will be helpful to have an idea what the `BaseEstimator` instances do with the `objective` parameter and whether it is truly necessary or could be a class attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the three different classes, maybe you can use traditional inheritance, overwriting an argument:

```
class FixedEstimator_Obj1(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['objective'] = 'obj_1'
        super(FixedEstimator_Obj1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

In the above example, this is calling the BaseEstimator `__init__` fixing the `objective` as keyword argument, but you could fix a positional argument too:

```
class FixedEstimator_Obj1(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FixedEstimator_Obj1, self).__init__('obj_1', *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Btw, watching Raymond Hettinger's talk The Art of Subclassing was a good time investment for me, you may like it: https://pyvideo.org/pycon-us-2012/the-art-of-subclassing.html :)

Comment: this looks useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance might be a solution here:

What you're  looking for is `super()`

super lets you refer implicitly to an object's parent class:

```
class BaseEstimator():
    def __init__(self, objective):
        self.objective = objective

    def some_method(self):
        return 'test_' + self.objective

class FixedEstimator_Obj1(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, objective):
        super().__init__(objective=objective)

class FixedEstimator_Obj2(BaseEstimator):
    def __init__(self, objective):
        super().__init__(objective=objective)


FixedEstimator_Obj1('obj_1').some_method()

FixedEstimator_Obj2('obj_2').some_method()
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to create a separate class for each `objective` parameter?

Because with how you've stated your problem, one class should be enough.

```
class BaseEstimator:
    def __init__(self, objective):
        self.objective = objective

    def some_method(self):
        print f'My objective is {self.objective}'

fe_obj1 = BaseEstimator('to love')
```

`fe_obj1.some_method()` outputs `My objective is to love.`

Comment: f-strings with python 2 `print` syntax? That's new.

Comment: The reason is that I have a module that works well with about 12 other classes. Now none of these classes take `objective` as input and the code has been written accordingly and I am not supposed to change that. This is an additional feature that I am adding to the module. These 12 other classes get imported from a library that has classes for each objective type and so once these classes are available in the required form, I'll call them depending on the objective type. I can't be passing the objective type on the fly here